# Is it advisable to vote up two/three questions/answers in order to make his/her reputation/points to 20, So that he can join chat room

Tags: discussion, new-users

PS: I don't know that other guy; I just want to help that user for the issue he is fighting for.

Sometimes I have observed that people just join Stack Overflow and ask a question. They have less than 20 points. I try to help them but the number of comments keep on increasing.

One of the reasons could be that the other person is just a newbie, stuck with a configuration issue or something. (I observed this issues mostly with newbies.)

Now the problem is that I can't ask that user to come to the chat room cause he doesn't have enough reputation.

How to solve this issue:

- Keep commenting on the question because he is not having enough reputation.
- Ask him to ask some good questions or answer some questions to earn points and by that time leave this issue. But if he is newbie then this thing doesn't make sense for him.
- Vote up his two questions, and ask one of your friend to vote up too or ask your four friends to vote up (P&C).

What should I do? Basically, what do Stack Exchange's laws (FAQs) say?

I feel this is kind of important because some of them are totally newbie and being stuck with configurations is frustrating for them.

Comment: I think there should be a feature request here -- allow any user with the 100 rep [create chat rooms](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/chat-rooms) privilege to invite users with under 20 rep to a chat room like the one created by the "continue this discussion in chat" link.

Answer (score 2):

Posts should be voted if they are worth being voted, not to give the opportunity to a user to use the chat. If you ask to your friends to vote a user's posts, then probably the Stack Exchange stuff would see this as voting anomalies.

Comment: Common dude... Gimme a solution.. I know this. Thats why i am asking.. And one more thing.. Stackexchange background process will not track it because I am not voting up on 100s or 1000s of questions.. It just two/three vote up, so Stackexchange background process will never be able to track it. I am asking for the right thing..What should be done..

Comment: You already reported the solution when you said you should suggest to the user to ask some good questions, or answer to questions. You asked what Stack Exchange rules are, and I don't think it makes any difference if the user gets two up-votes because you told a friend of yours to vote his posts, or if he gets hundred up-votes from your friend just because you told them to vote.